# list of canonical math operators

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

some time ago I started to pay kind of much attention to math in latex, it is well known that

```
$sin x$
```

and

```
$\sin x$
```

are quite different, are there full list of such a canonical operators?

for example 2 days ago I figured out that there's also support for

```
$\min \max$
```

So I asked muself how many operators are supported this way

Comment: As most people use the amsmath package, have a look at its manual, it has a list of what is offered (page 18).

Comment: You can create anyone you want with `\DeclareMathOperator\whatever{whatever}`.

Comment: @Manuel, yes, i know that there are \mathrm{} and \operatorname{}, I am more interested how many operators are supported way I asked :)

Comment: @daleif, so amsmath/mathtools handles func/operators names automatically? (never paid attention before)

Comment: any tex tutorial should have the basic list, although other packages may add more, see for example `texdoc maths-symbols` table 8

Comment: @M.Mass not, these are the ones that are predefined. Mathematicians make up a lot more operators/functions than are on the list. So often you will have to declare them your self, which is very easy, see  `\DeclareMathOperator`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's easy to find the complete list of the predefined operators by looking in `amsopn.sty`:

```
\def\arccos{\qopname\relax o{arccos}}
\def\arcsin{\qopname\relax o{arcsin}}
\def\arctan{\qopname\relax o{arctan}}
\def\arg{\qopname\relax o{arg}}
\def\cos{\qopname\relax o{cos}}
\def\cosh{\qopname\relax o{cosh}}
\def\cot{\qopname\relax o{cot}}
\def\coth{\qopname\relax o{coth}}
\def\csc{\qopname\relax o{csc}}
\def\deg{\qopname\relax o{deg}}
\def\det{\qopname\relax m{det}}
\def\dim{\qopname\relax o{dim}}
\def\exp{\qopname\relax o{exp}}
\def\gcd{\qopname\relax m{gcd}}
\def\hom{\qopname\relax o{hom}}
\def\inf{\qopname\relax m{inf}}
\def\injlim{\qopname\relax m{inj\,lim}}
\def\ker{\qopname\relax o{ker}}
\def\lg{\qopname\relax o{lg}}
\def\lim{\qopname\relax m{lim}}
\def\liminf{\qopname\relax m{lim\,inf}}
\def\limsup{\qopname\relax m{lim\,sup}}
\def\ln{\qopname\relax o{ln}}
\def\log{\qopname\relax o{log}}
\def\max{\qopname\relax m{max}}
\def\min{\qopname\relax m{min}}
\def\Pr{\qopname\relax m{Pr}}
\def\projlim{\qopname\relax m{proj\,lim}}
\def\sec{\qopname\relax o{sec}}
\def\sin{\qopname\relax o{sin}}
\def\sinh{\qopname\relax o{sinh}}
\def\sup{\qopname\relax m{sup}}
\def\tan{\qopname\relax o{tan}}
\def\tanh{\qopname\relax o{tanh}}
```

Maybe it's better to list them in a different way. First the operators that don't push limits above and below in display style (those with `\relax o`:

```
\arccos  \arcsin  \arctan  \arg  \cos   \cosh  \cot
\csc     \deg     \dim     \exp  \hom   \inf   \ker
\lg      \log     \sec     \sin  \sinh  \tan   \tanh
```

and then the ones that do (with `\relax m`):

```
\det  \gcd  \injlim  \lim      \liminf  \limsup
\max  \min  \Pr      \projlim  \sup

\varinjlim  \varprojlim  \varliminf  \varlimsup
```

(the last row lists some specially defined operators).

If you need other operators not listed here, you can use them with

```
\operatorname{foo}
\operatorname*{foo}
```

(for a one shot case) or define them with

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\foo}{foo}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\foo}{foo}
```

Note that the control sequence name *need not* be the same as the operator name; it's usually done in order to be remembered, but if the command turns out to already being defined, one has to choose a different name.

The `*` states that the limits are pushed above and below in display style.